# SQL -Pivoting a column from a table which have Unique records

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, database-administration

I am trying to pivot a table to Row which have duplicate records on all columns but, a unique ID Named ([log_ID]) at the last columns  . I wont log_ID field pivoted and given dynamic name as log_ID_1 ,log_ID_2 ...etc FYI - THE log_ID's is not static they change at every execution's they could be less or more .

My table retrieve records as  this .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gup0.png)

I wont it be displayed as this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg4u6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not stated what database you are using so I'm assuming it's a fairly recent version of SQL Server..

Add a column to your dataset that generates a number for each `log_id` like this...

I've recreated your sample data with

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Emp_ID int, [Name] varchar(20), log_ID int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    (6354, 'John Doe', 752),
    (6354, 'John Doe', 653),
    (6354, 'John Doe', 635),
    (6354, 'John Doe', 124),
    (6354, 'John Doe', 874),
    (6354, 'John Doe', 254)

SELECT
    [Emp_ID], [Name], [log_ID], 
    CONCAT('log_ID_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY Emp_ID) ) as col
    FROM @t
```

This gives the following results

[image]

**NOTE** The `ROW_NUMBER()` function needs an `ORDER BY`. I use `Emp_ID` even though they are all the same so that the results *should* be returned in the order they sit in the table. You can change the order by clause to order the log_ID's in whatever order you like.

Now in your report, add a matrix control, add a row group by `emp_id` and `name`, and add a column group grouped by `col`

If the table has more than one emp_id then these will appear on separate rows in the report.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you !!  This works perfectly but my records are too large (>500k records) to put it on a Matrix report will slag and performance is going to be slow  . how can  I implement this in a pivoted  sql syntax . as in pivoting the [EMPID] ,[Name],  LOG_ID_1 ,   LOG_ID_2 , LOG_ID_3 .... as column headers and results  6354 , JohnDoe ,752,653... will be as results .

Comment: You need to ask a new question. But basically you will need to dynamically generate your PIVOT statement. Modify this answer to insert the results into a temp table then you will need to look for distinct 'col' in the temp table and dynamically build the pivot statement.